# Why is my Ethereum Wallet balance wrong, even after sync? Etherscan vs. Wallet mismatch

Tags: ether, wallets, balances

Why does my Ethereum wallet disagree with Etherscan? It's been 24h. I made the transaction from Kraken myself, so I know the Wallet is wrong.

I don't think this is a duplicate question, because I've downloaded all the blocks.

Complete Noob.

Please help, thank you

[image]

Comment: maybe your wallet isn't synced with the network, try to run it in light mode